Error in hash and it’s equivalence with the index of an array
I want to repeat a process for every key in a hash, with numeric keys. So there are 3 possibilities, with 3 if, and each one compares the value of the index of an array, so that if that position eq to "sp", "sp2" or "sp3" it will search in a document some value so then it can be printed. It doesn´t work and every times gives me only one value, i would like to get the values that correspond with the hash. For example the hash could be %grupos=(1,'A',2,'G',3,'J')
The document .txt is:
HS0.32 
CS0,77
CD0.62
CT0,59 
C10,77
C20,62
C30,59
OS0.73
OD0,6
O10,73
O20,6 
NS0.75

The code is:
@ hibridaciones=("sp","sp2",sp3")
%grupos=(1,'A',2,'G',3,'J')
open (covalencia,"<", "cov.txt") or die "$!\n";
print keys %grupos;
keys %grupos; 
foreach my $z (keys %grupos) { 
    print "\n$z\n";
    if (@hibridaciones[my $z-1] eq "sp") {
        while (my $line = <covalencia>) {
            if ( $line=~/^C1/) {
                $line =~s/C1//;
                $radio=$line;
                print "\n$radio";
            }
        }
    }
    if (@hibridaciones[my $z-1] eq "sp2") {
        while (my $line = <covalencia>) {
            if ($line=~/^C2/) {
                $line =~s/C2//;
                $radio=$line;
                print "\n$radio";
            }
        }
    }
    if (@hibridaciones[my $z-1] eq "sp3") {
        while (my $line = <covalencia>) {
            if ($line=~/^C3/) {
                $line =~s/C3//;
                $radio=$line;
                print "\n$radio";
            }
        }
    }
}
close (covalencia);


You have multiple typos in your code. Please do not post code that is not exactly like what you are asking about. Copy and paste code directly from the file you used when you got your result.

What is this [my $z-1] supposed to do? my $z will declare a new variable, which will be considered 0, so the expression and array index will be -1 for all instances. It will give multiple warnings, so I am guessing you are not using either use warnings or use strict. This is a very bad idea.

You cannot exhaust a file handle and then search it again. You have to rewind it, or reopen the file handle. At and after the end of file, <cov> will only return undef.

Crossposted to Reddit/perl.

There are a number of issues with your code. It does not seem likely that you have actually ran this code, because it is broken, with a missing double quote that destroys the rest of the code, plus missing semi-colons, which are also wreaking havoc.
But you also have some design errors, or poor choices. I'll go through your code below.
Firstly, always use use strict; use warnings;. These two pragmas will prevent you from making simple mistakes that are difficult to discover. It may be difficult in the beginning, but coding without them is ridiculously dangerous.
@ hibridaciones=("sp","sp2",sp3")
%grupos=(1,'A',2,'G',3,'J')

Two missing semi-colons. The space between @ and the array name is bad, but the code still works. But you do have a missing double quote around sp3.
open (covalencia,"<", "cov.txt") or die "$!\n";

Three argument open with specific mode is good. But this code still gives a warning for the bareword covalencia. The better option is to use a lexical variable, e.g. open my $fh, "<", .... The variable name $fh is often used as a file handle.
keys %grupos; 

This statement in void context does nothing.
foreach my $z (keys %grupos) { 

You should use variable names that are self-explanatory, this will save you a lot of pain. So, you should use my $key here.
    if (@hibridaciones[my $z-1] eq "sp") {

There are many things wrong here.

First, @ is used for an array slice. If you just have one element, you use $. This will trigger a warning from use warnings.
my $z will create a new variable named $z. If you have warnings enabled, it will warn you about that. This means that the array element checked will always be -1, because 0-1=-1. The element -1 is the last element in the array.
The logic is wrong here. You are asking what is in the array that you yourself declared. This is not relevant for the code, and you can replace it with a comment: if ( $key == 1 ) {  # this is "sp".

Note that the last point here makes the entire @hibridaciones array redundant.

        while (my $line = <covalencia>) {

You can only use a filehandle to the end of file once. After that, <covalencia> will return undef. Which means the following while loops will not run at all. You should put the lines from the file in an array, and loop over that instead. E.g. for my $line (@lines)
            if ( $line=~/^C1/) {
                $line =~s/C1//;

While technically not wrong, using s/// on a loop variable puts you at risk of a hard to detect bug. When using a for/foreach loop, the loop variable is aliased to the original, so changing the loop variable will change the original. This will not happen in this case, since you are reading from a file, but since my recommendation is that you use another solution, this will be relevant later.
My recommendation here is to capture the end of the line instead, which is a non-destructive option: if ($line =~ /^C1(.*)/)... and then print $1. Or use say, which adds a newline automatically (see my code below).
                $radio=$line;
                print "\n$radio";

The $radio variable is redundant and can be deleted.

All in all, what I end up with is this:
use strict;
use warnings;        # never code without strict and warnings enabled
use feature 'say';   # say $1 replaces print "$1\n"

my %grupos = (1,'A',2,'G',3,'J');
open (my $covalencia,"<", "cov.txt") or die "$!\n";
my @lines = <$covalencia>;    # your file is now in @lines
close ($covalencia);

foreach my $key (keys %grupos) {
    say "----- $key -----";
    if ($key == 1) {   # "sp"
        for my $line (@lines) {        # now we can loop as much as we want
            if ( $line=~ /^C1(.*)/) {  # capture to $1
                say $1;                # print $1
            }
        }
    } elsif ($key == 2) {   # "sp2"
        for my $line (@lines) {
            if ($line=~ /^C2(.*)/) {
                say $1;
            }
        }
    } elsif ($key == 3) {   # "sp3"
        for my $line (@lines) {
            if ($line=~ /^C3(.*)/) {
                say $1;
            }
        }
    }
}

Which gives the output:
----- 1 -----
0,77
----- 3 -----
0,59
----- 2 -----
0,62

